# What is the simplest way to emulate a bidirectional UDP connection between two ports on localhost?

Tags: udp, socat

I'm adapting code that used a direct connection between udp://localhost:9080 and udp://localhost:5554 to insert ports 19080 and 15554.  On one side, 9080 now talks and listens to 19080 instead of directly to 5554.  Similarly, 5554 now talks and listens to 15554.  What's missing is a bidirectional connection between 19080 and 15554.  All the socat examples I've seen seem to ignore this simplest of cases in favor of specialized ones of limited usefulness.

I previously seemed to have success with:

`sudo socat UDP4:localhost:19080 UDP4:localhost:15554 &`

but I found that it may have been due to a program bug that bypassed the connection.  It no longer works.

I've also been given tentative suggestions to use a pair of more cryptic commands that likewise don't work:

`sudo socat UDP4-RECVFROM:19080,fork UDP4-SENDTO:localhost:15554 &`

`sudo socat UDP4-RECVFROM:15554,fork UDP4-SENDTO:localhost:19080 &`

and additionally seem to overcomplicate the manpage statement that "Socat  is  a  command  line based utility that establishes two bidirectional byte streams and transfers data between them."

I can see from Wireshark that both sides are correctly using their respective sides of the connection to send UDP packets, but neither side is receiving what the other side has sent, due to the opacity of socat used in either of these ways.

Has anyone implemented this simplest of cases simply, reproducibly, and unambiguously?  It was suggested to me as a way around writing my own emulator to pass packets back and forth between the ports, but the time spent getting socat to cooperate could likewise be put to better use.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it appears possible that the two 'more cryptic' commands might cause a non-desirable loop... perhaps the destination ports could be modified as shown below and perhaps that may help achieve your objective.  This may not be viable based on your application as you may need to adjust your receive sockets accordingly.

```
sudo socat UDP4-RECVFROM:19080,fork UDP4-SENDTO:localhost:5554 &

sudo socat UDP4-RECVFROM:15554,fork UDP4-SENDTO:localhost:9080 &
```

Answer (score 0):

You use fix ports, and you do not specify if one direction is initiating the transfers.

Therefore the datagram addresses are to prefer. Something like the following command should do the trick:

```
socat \
    UDP-DATAGRAM:localhost:9080,bind=localhost:19080,sourceport=9080 \
    UDP-DATAGRAM:localhost:5554,bind=localhost:15554,sourceport=5554
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the 5-digit port numbers belong in the socat commands.  The connections from or to 9988, 9080, and 5554 are direct existing connections.  I only need socat for the emulated connections that would exist if an actual appliance existed.

Comment: I give in, I do not understand the emulation.